# Foreign Key Constraint Error SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, foreign-keys

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "fk_OrderID". The conflict occurred in database "CM", table
>   "dbo.Order", column 'OrderID'.

I am receiving this error. I have looked up other responses on this site but I am still confused (I am a little slow). I have made sure `Order` (which has my primary key) is loading before `OrderTotal` (which has my foreign key), and when looking at my two `CSV` files for `Order` and `OrderTotal` I cannot seem to find a mistake or any different values.

I originally ran this code two months ago and had no problems, but now I always get this error.

`Order` has **200** rows and `OrderTotal` has around **600** so there are repeats. Does this have any relation at all? I never thought it did but now I do not know.

I am sorry for the repeated question, I am just a little slow at picking up concepts and would appreciate any help in clearing this up. Google has given some good answers but I still cannot figure out my problem.

Comment: Looks like some orders from the file already exists in database. It is a reason of this constraint. I not know, there is some setting to skip such duplicates in sql-server. But, in any case, you can upload your file in temp table with same schema and check what orders already exists by join.

Comment: since foreign key should reference to something in the OrderTotal table ,make sure that record is available first ...

Comment: Your error seems to indicate that the OrderID that the inserted records has a foreign key relation to does not exist. Make sure you first insert the record which your foreign key refers to. 
If you'd want more help for you specific situation we'd need more information. Usually a database schema and a query are required to give accurate help.

Answer (score 0):

Your query may have tried insert an `OrderID` into `OrderTotal` table that doesn't exist in `Order` Table.

Recheck the values in `OrderTotal` Table as well as `Order` Table.

There can be spaces or some special characters which are easily missed.
Ensure to avoid them before inserting to table